# @DataProvider is disallowed for this location

Tags: java, selenium, testng, selenium-rc

I am trying to test the registration page with **data driven** application using `TestNG` Framework and am getting this below error.

```
The annotation @DataProvider is disallowed for this location
Syntax error on token ";", { expected after this token
Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody
```

Answer (score 0):

You should provide the code that does not compile. I'll make a guess without being able to see your code though.

I think that the declaration following the annotation @DataProvider is incorrect. Note that this annotation is supposed to be used on methods. [DataProvider javadoc](http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/annotations/DataProvider.html)

Example

```
@DataProvider
Object[][] yourProviderName() {
    return new Object[][] { { new Integer(10),
            new Integer(20) } };
}
```